# Server freezes after installing Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 on Dell R900

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge

I tried this a week ago, and then went with CentOS, but decided I would rather be on Ubuntu server.  So whenever I install Ubuntu server, after the install finishes and reboots, I remove the install media, and right as it tries to boot from the drive it freezes.  If I go to boot options, and select the hard drive, it freezes instantly.  Ubuntu desktop had no problems, Centos had none.  What could be happening here?

I am running on a perc 6/i with a single drive configured as a virtual drive.
Server is Dell R900, 4 CPU's(don't remember which)
128gb Ram
Single 500gb drive(for now)

Edit:  I thought I put 14.04.2 on, but I was using 14.10. Going to try 14.04.02 now, but still would like to know why it freezes with 14.10

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention it in your question, so I'll assume you haven't tried it: edit the commandline in boot options and remove the 'quiet' directive. That should at least show you where it freezes.

Comment: How could I do that?  I don't even make it to the grub boot loader.  The last thing the screen shows is "Press ctrl + e to set up the dell remote access console" and then a newline and blinking cursor.  Or if I go to the boot menu and choose the boot drive, it freezes right after I hit enter/never shows anything else.